# Showing the land cover class area in the Google Earth Engine chart

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, land-classification

I've produced a classified map in GEE and trying to create a chart showing the area for each landcover class. The code I'm using is as follows,

```
var classNames = ['vegetation Covers', 'Water Bodies', 'Urban Areas', 'Barren Lands'];
var create_chart = function(classifiedImage, mumbai, classNames){ // for classNames, create a list of your classes as strings
  var options = {
    hAxis: {title: 'Land Cover Class'},
    vAxis: {title: 'Area in Kilometers'},
    title: 'Area in KM by Land Cover Class',
    series: { // set color for each class
      0: {color: 'green'}, // Vegetation covers
      1: {color: 'blue'}, // Water bodies
      2: {color: 'black'}, // Urban areas
      3: {color: 'yellow'}} // Barren lands
  };
  var areaChart = ui.Chart.image.byClass({
    image: ee.Image.pixelArea().addBands(classifiedImage),
    classBand: 'classification', 
    scale: 30,
    region: mumbai,
    reducer: ee.Reducer.sum()

  }).setSeriesNames(classNames)
  .setOptions(options)
  ;
  print(areaChart);
};

create_chart(classifiedImage, mumbai, classNames);
```

`classifiedImage` is the output image of the classification. `mumbai` is the area of interest.

The chart should show the landcover classes on the x-axis and the corresponding area in kilometers on the y-axis. But the chart produce by this code is showing the number of pixels on the y-axis.

[image]
I understand, I have not specified any rule for area calculation in the code. I have tried changing the code but always get errors. Can anyone suggest, **how to get the desired output here (area in kilometers on the y-axis)?**

I'm using the Landsat images here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not showing the number of pixels, its showing the area in meters, since that's the units on pixelArea.  Divide that image by 1,000,000 to get sqkm.